# How do I have a link in an iframe change the parent window?

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I have a page of a lot of images in a gallery format. When you click on an image, an iframe changes to have information about that image and a link that brings you to another page (of more detailed pictures of the original image in the same gallery style format).

My issue, is that since the link is in an iframe, the new page loads in the iframe. Is there a way, or a target="whatever" command, to make that link effect the parent page?

Answer (score 2):

In the link add `target=_parent`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, but it's still loading in the iframe :/